# Replace string with str_replace - wordpress wp_get_archives counter

Tags: php

```
<li>
    <a href="http://localhost/nnn/wp5/index.php/2015/05/">May 2015</a>&nbsp;(10)
</li>
```

I try to make it in standar way:

```
$variable = wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly','show_post_count' => 'true') );

$variable = str_replace( '(', '<span class="cat-count">', $variable);
$variable = str_replace( ')', '</span>', $variable);
echo $variable;
```

But this doesn't work.

Also read about unicode:

```
$variable = preg_replace('/\p{Zs}/u', '_', $variable);
```

But also nothing... What I miss?

ANSWER :

Typical for wordpress:

```
$variable = wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly','show_post_count' => 'true', 'echo' => 0) );
```

This what a problem. Default is echo => 1, so variable was blank.

```
'echo' => 0
```

THANKS FOR HELP

Comment: what do your `$variable` hold ?

Comment: are you sure those are `(` and `)`, and not something goofy like `&lpar;` and `&rpar;`?

Comment: In html it return : <li><a href="http://localhost/nnn/wp5/index.php/2015/05/">May 2015</a>&nbsp;(10)</li>

Comment: You can do a self-answered post

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved.

```
$variable = wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly','show_post_count' => 'true') );

$variable = str_replace( '(', '<span class="cat-count">', $variable);
$variable = str_replace( ')', '</span>', $variable);
echo $variable;
```

By default wordpress wp_get_archives is setted as "echo". Solution for this was to set "echo" to false:

```
$variable = wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly','show_post_count' => 'true', 'echo' => 0) )
```

and now $variable is not blank.